# When in MS Word we add new words to the dictionary, Where do they save?

Tags: microsoft-office

I use MS Office Proofing Tools. On the other hand, I have to install a fresh Windows. Obviously after Windows installation, the words added in old OS will disappear. So, I am seeking a trick to save these words and add them to the Fresh Windows.

Can I find them some where?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Word 2010, when you add a word to the dictionary, it appears in a text file here:

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UProof\CUSTOM.DIC
```

You can copy this file over to your new installation.

Comment: The user name might not match the actual folder name, and Windows could be installed in a different drive. You can use `%AppData%\Microsoft\UProof\CUSTOM.DIC` instead.